# Is it possible to inject a mix of runtime value and normal dependencies using tsyringe?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, tsyringe

I'm using [@launchtray/tsyringe](https://github.com/launchtray/tsyringe) (a fork of Microsoft [tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe) with async initialization support) which is quite handy.

I'd like to implement something like the following:

A orchestration service whose constructor accepts dependency services (can be injected using @inject decorator) and a runtime value:

```
@injectable()
class OrchestrationService {
  constructor(
    @inject(ServiceA) private dependencyA: ServiceA,
    @inject(ServiceA) private dependencyB: ServiceB,
    runtimeValue: string,
  ) {
    this.init(runtimeValue);
  }
}
```

And then I can somehow resolve the instance using a runtime value:

```
const orchestrationService = container.resolve<OrchestrationService>(runtimeValue);
```

I don't know all possible runtime values therefore cannot register them beforehand.

I am wondering if injecting runtime value is possible and how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question in tsyringe github repo and Andrey Khapugin answered my question. It's not perfect but I reckon it's the best we can get.

> you can register value in container
>
> ```
> const SomeToken:InjectionToken<string> = "MyToken";
>
> class Service{
>   constructor(
>     @inject(ServiceA) private dependencyA: ServiceA,
>     @inject(ServiceA) private dependencyB: ServiceB,
>     @inject(SomeToken) runtimeValue: string,
>   )
> }
>
> container.registerInstance(SomeToken, "runtimeValue");
> container.resolve(SomeToken); // runtimeValue
> container.resolve(Service); // Service instance
> ```
>
> https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#injecting-primitive-values-named-injection

https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/issues/193#issuecomment-1084181366